# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection') at connectToMongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const connectToMongo = async () => {
  try {
    mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
    mongoose.connect(mongoURI);
    console.log('Mongo connected');
    const fetched_data = await mongoose.connection.db.collection('book_desc');
    fetched_data.find({}).toArray(function (err, data) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else console.log(data);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit();
  }
};
```

I'm trying to fetch data and it's giving an error. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

`mongoose.connection.db` is:

> The `mongodb.Db` instance, set when the connection is opened

You should make sure to access the `.db` property when the connection is opened successfully. `mongoose.connect()` is asynchronous and it returns a promise, you can use `async/await` syntax sugar to wait for asynchronous code to accomplish.

> **Blocking** methods execute synchronously and **non-blocking** methods execute asynchronously.

The `mongoose.connect()` performs an I/O operation and it's **non-blocking**. This means the code after `mongoose.connect()` will run before the I/O operation is accomplished.

This will work

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { config } from '../../config';

mongoose.set('debug', true);
console.log(mongoose.version);

(async function main() {
    try {
        console.log('before connection', mongoose.connection.db);
        await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);
        console.log('after connection', mongoose.connection.db);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
    }
})();
```

Logs:

```
before connection undefined
after connection Db {
  s: {
    options: {
      enableUtf8Validation: true,
      forceServerObjectId: false,
      pkFactory: [Object],
      raw: false,
      readPreference: [ReadPreference],
      retryWrites: true
    },
    readPreference: ReadPreference {
      mode: 'primary',
      tags: undefined,
      hedge: undefined,
      maxStalenessSeconds: undefined,
      minWireVersion: undefined
    },
    bsonOptions: {
      raw: false,
      useBigInt64: false,
      promoteLongs: true,
      promoteValues: true,
      promoteBuffers: false,
      ignoreUndefined: false,
      bsonRegExp: false,
      serializeFunctions: false,
      fieldsAsRaw: {},
      enableUtf8Validation: true
    },
    pkFactory: { createPk: [Function: createPk] },
    readConcern: undefined,
    writeConcern: undefined,
    namespace: MongoDBNamespace { db: 'test', collection: undefined }
  },
  client: <ref *1> MongoClient {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      topologyDescriptionChanged: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    _eventsCount: 1,
    _maxListeners: 0,
    mongoLogger: MongoLogger {
      error: [Function: bound log],
      warn: [Function: bound log],
      info: [Function: bound log],
      debug: [Function: bound log],
      trace: [Function: bound log],
      componentSeverities: [Object],
      maxDocumentLength: 1000,
      logDestination: [Object]
    },
    s: {
      url: 'mongodb+srv://slideshowp2:xtEBJWGgFXSNbv6t@cluster0.d1avjia.mongodb.net',
      bsonOptions: [Object],
      namespace: [MongoDBNamespace],
      hasBeenClosed: false,
      sessionPool: [ServerSessionPool],
      activeSessions: Set(0) {},
      options: [Getter],
      readConcern: [Getter],
      writeConcern: [Getter],
      readPreference: [Getter],
      isMongoClient: [Getter]
    },
    connectionLock: undefined,
    topology: Topology {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 26,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      client: [Circular *1],
      selectServerAsync: [Function (anonymous)],
      s: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(waitQueue)]: [List]
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(options)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      hosts: [Array],
      credentials: [MongoCredentials],
      compressors: [Array],
      connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
      directConnection: false,
      driverInfo: [Object],
      enableUtf8Validation: true,
      forceServerObjectId: false,
      heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
      keepAlive: true,
      keepAliveInitialDelay: 120000,
      loadBalanced: false,
      localThresholdMS: 15,
      maxConnecting: 2,
      maxIdleTimeMS: 0,
      maxPoolSize: 100,
      minPoolSize: 0,
      minHeartbeatFrequencyMS: 500,
      monitorCommands: false,
      noDelay: true,
      pkFactory: [Object],
      raw: false,
      readPreference: [ReadPreference],
      retryReads: true,
      retryWrites: true,
      serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 30000,
      socketTimeoutMS: 0,
      srvMaxHosts: 0,
      srvServiceName: 'mongodb',
      waitQueueTimeoutMS: 0,
      zlibCompressionLevel: 0,
      dbName: 'test',
      userSpecifiedAuthSource: false,
      userSpecifiedReplicaSet: false,
      srvHost: 'cluster0.d1avjia.mongodb.net',
      tls: true,
      mongoLoggerOptions: [Object],
      metadata: [Object],
      replicaSet: 'atlas-zy5qpa-shard-0',
      [Symbol(@@mdb.enableMongoLogger)]: false
    }
  }
}
```

---

This will **not** work:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { config } from '../../config';

mongoose.set('debug', true);
console.log(mongoose.version);

(async function main() {
    try {
        console.log('before connection', mongoose.connection.db);
        mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);
        console.log('after connection', mongoose.connection.db);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } finally {
        await mongoose.connection.close();
    }
})();
```

Logs:

```
7.3.2
before connection undefined
after connection undefined
```

You can learn more from [Overview of Blocking vs Non-Blocking](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/blocking-vs-non-blocking)